# Did Dumbledore Raise Harry Like a Pig For Slaughter?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore

Can't seem to find if there is already a question similar - though I do think there may.

Two similar questions; did Dumbledore really raise Harry like a pig for slaughter, and did he know Harry would survive in the end? At Severus puts it, 
["you kept him alive so he can die at the proper moment," and, "you've raised him like a pig for slaughter."](https://youtu.be/iqyf-kJWwIg?t=174) It seems that this is a complete betrayal of trust, though I have a feeling there is more than meets the eye (I.E, Dumbledore didn't really betray him). Did Dumbledore know Harry would live, or was he really just doing everything for the *greater good*?

Please provide references for your answers; quotes, etc..

Comment: Basically, yes. Though at least he did (eventually) tell Harry about it and gave him the choice of whether to go into the slaughterhouse or not.

Comment: This is starting to sound like the Matrix